# SQLAlchemy: @property mapping?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following models:

```
class Details(db.Model):

    details_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    details_main = db.Column(db.String(50))
    details_desc = db.Column(db.String(50))

class Data(db.Model):

    data_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    details_main = db.Column(db.String(50))

    @property
    def details_desc(self):

        result = object_session(self).\
            scalar(
                select([Details.details_desc]).
                    where(Details.details_main == self.details_main)
            )

        return result
```

Now, I would like to run query using filter which depends on defined property. I get empty results (of course proper data is in DB). It doesn't work because, probably, I have to map this property. The question is how to do this? (One limitation: FK are not allowed).

```
Data.query\
    .filter(Data.details_desc == unicode('test'))\
    .all()
```

Comment: What do you mean FKs are not allowed? The `details_main` columns on `Data` and `Details` can be used as foreign keys, provided that they're unique.

Comment: The best option would be defining `details_main` and `details_desc` in `Data` as FK, but in this project DB design doesn't allow FK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this with a regular [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) and an [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html):

```
class Data(db.Model):
    data_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    details_main = db.Column(db.String(50))

    details = relationship(
        Details,
        primaryjoin=remote(Details.details_main) == foreign(details_main))
    details_desc = association_proxy('details', 'details_desc')
```

Since there are no foreign keys in the schema, you need to tell SQLAlchemy yourself what the join condition for the `relationship` should be. This is what the `remote()` and `foreign()` annotations do.

With that in place, you can use an `association_proxy` "across" the relationship to create a property on `Data` which will work the way you want.

Comment: Could you provide solution with hybrid property? Simple replace `@property` -> `@hybrid_property` causes `UnmappedInstanceError`.

Comment: Didn't `relationship` work? A simple replacement of `@property` with `@hybrid_property` should not be expected to work.

Comment: Without `self` (in `Details.details_main == self.details_main`) error appears: `ArgumentError: relationship 'details_desc' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>)`

Comment: So, now I've created a solution that I've actually tested to work. Sorry about the half-assed attempt earlier.

Comment: Great, you're welcome! Thanks for the accept, would you mind upvoting as well if "the answer is useful"?